# navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia works well on Desktop and Android but throws error on IOS mobile

Tags: javascript, multimedia

I want to capture audio, video in javascript. Below code works well on desktop and android. but it throws error on IOS mobile. Is this compability issue of the getUserMedia API? Any other alternative for the same will also be helpful.

```html
<video id="vid" muted autoplay></video>

<script>
    video = document.getElementById('vid');
    video.style.width = document.width + 'px';
    video.style.height = document.height + 'px';
    video.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
    video.setAttribute('muted', '');
    video.setAttribute('playsinline', '');

    var constraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: {
            facingMode: 'user'
        }
    }

    console.log("out before")
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function success(stream) {
        console.log("hbvjdhb")
        video.srcObject = stream;
    });
</script>
```